# Best way to select random rows in redshift without order by

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

i have to select a set of rows (like 200 unique rows) from 200 million rows at once without order by and it must be efficient.

Comment: Maybe try `where random() > 0.7 limit 100`?

Comment: The problem with LIMIT is that this will bias towards the sort order of the table(s) involved AND with a limit of 200 the rows returned will be from the slice (or slices) that return values first.  Definitely not random.  The reason you need ORDER BY is to remove this bias.  You can sub select on the RANDOM(), as you are doing here, then sort a much smaller set, and then apply the LIMIT.

Comment: There are a number of pseudorandom processes that can be deployed without an ORDER BY.  How truly random do you need this sample to be?

Comment: @BillWeiner  want it very randomised

Comment: @Dumbo do you have integer ids in the table schema?

Comment: What are the sort keys of the table?

Comment: @damjad i have to select entire row without any information about the table besides  the table name(orders), and schema name(big_table1).  I was able to do using offset but not efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are experiencing sorting 200M rows can take a while and if all you want is 200 rows then this is an expense you shouldn't need to pay.  However, you do need to sort on a random value if you want to select 200 rows that are random.  Otherwise the sort order of the base tables and the order of reply from the Redshift slices will meaningfully skew you sample.

You can get around this by sampling down (through a random process) so a much more manageable number of rows, then sort by the random value and pick your final 200 rows.  While this does need to sort rows it does it upon a significantly smaller number which will speed things up considerably.

```
select a, b from (
  select a, b, random() as ranno 
  from test_table)
where ranno < .005
order by ranno
limit 200;
```

You start with 200M rows.  Select .5% of them in the WHERE clause.  Then order these 10,000 rows before selecting 200.  This should speed things up and maintain the randomness of the selection.

Comment: `select * from (select *, random() as ranno from "order"."info"."table1") where ranno < .005 order by ranno limit 200`  . Changed it to this as mentioned above still taking more than 10 min. @BillWeiner

Comment: Can you post the explain plan or the actual execution report?  There are a number of reasons that it could be slow - poor query plan, queue overload, large return size / slow connection.   I have lots of ideas on possible issues but let’s get some data

Answer (score 0):

Sampling down your data to a reasonable percentage like 10%,5%,1%,.. etc should bring your volume to a manageable size. Then you can order by the sample and choose the count of rows you need.

```
select * from (select *, random() as sample 
               from "table") 
where sample < .01 
order by sample limit 200
```

The following is an expansion on the question which I found useful for me that others might find helpful as well. In my case, I had a huge table which I could split by a key field value into smaller subsets, but even after splitting it the volume per individual subset would stay very large (10s of millions of rows) and I still needed to sample it anyway. I was initially concerned that the sampling won't work on the subset I created using `With` statement, but it turned out this is not the case. I compared the distribution of the sample across all different meaningful keys afterwards between the full subset (20 million) and the sample (30K) and I got almost the exact distribution which worked great. Sample code below:

```
With subset as (select * from "table" Where Key_field='XYZ')
select * from (select *, random() as sample 
               from subset) s
where s.sample < .01 
order by s.sample limit 200
```